# Want to prevent default signalR OnDisconnect only from a certain view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

Right now, I have overridden SignalR's OnDisconnect Method as follows:

```
public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    if (this.Context.User != null)
    {
        string userName = this.Context.User.Identity.Name;
        var repo = new LobbyRepository();
        Clients.Group("Lobby").remove(userName);
        repo.RemoveFromLobby(userName);
    }
    return base.OnDisconnected();
}
```

However, this code is reached every time the user navigates to any view, temporarily breaking the signalR connection.  How can I prevent this from happening only when the user is requesting a certain view?

Answer (score 0):

The connection can be maintained as long you are in the same page, if you navigate away, the connection ends.

You can use Ajax to replace the content of your page, using a technique named "click hijacking" https://web.archive.org/web/20160305021055/http://mislav.net/2011/03/click-hijack/

But remember, the connection is associated to your page.

Cheers.